# Styling a fails if line break in hypertext

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm styling hyperlinks in my website but noticed the CSS I have applied does not work if there is a line break in the link.

```css
<style>.text-rich-text {
  width: 400px;
}

.text-rich-text a {
  color: #02585c;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text-rich-text a::after {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 173, 181, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  bottom: -6px;
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
  height: calc(100% - 8px);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0, 2.05);
}

.text-rich-text a:hover:after {
  left: 0;
  bottom: -2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="text-rich-text">
  Les entreprises doivent pouvoir établir, avec précision et rigueur, le temps <a>réellement et exclusivement</a> passé par le <a>Jeune Docteur à la réalisation</a> d’opérations de <a>recherche, toute détermination</a> forfaitaire étant exclue (BOI-BIC-RICI-10-10-10-30,
  §70 et 80).
</div>
```

Thank you very much for your help.
Cheers,
Joachim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try wrapping your components too.

```html
<div class="text-rich-text">
  Les entreprises doivent pouvoir établir, avec précision et rigueur, le temps <a>réellement et exclusivement</a> passé par le <a>Jeune Docteur à la réalisation</a> d’opérations de <a>recherche, toute détermination</a> forfaitaire étant exclue (BOI-BIC-RICI-10-10-10-30,
  §70 et 80).
</div>
<style>.text-rich-text {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  text-align: justify;
}

.text-rich-text a {
  color: #02585c;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text-rich-text a::after {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 173, 181, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  bottom: -6px;
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
  height: calc(100% - 8px);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0, 2.05);
}

.text-rich-text a:hover:after {
  left: 0;
  bottom: -2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you create a graphical element/line, with your pseude-element, and that element won't be broken...

Here's a workaround, though: You can add `white-space: nowrap;` to the CSS rule for the links to avoid them to break:

```css
<style>.text-rich-text {
  width: 400px;
}

.text-rich-text a {
  color: #02585c;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.text-rich-text a::after {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 173, 181, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  bottom: -6px;
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
  height: calc(100% - 8px);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0, 2.05);
}

.text-rich-text a:hover:after {
  left: 0;
  bottom: -2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="text-rich-text">
  Les entreprises doivent pouvoir établir, avec précision et rigueur, le temps <a>réellement et exclusivement</a> passé par le <a>Jeune Docteur à la réalisation</a> d’opérations de <a>recherche, toute détermination</a> forfaitaire étant exclue (BOI-BIC-RICI-10-10-10-30,
  §70 et 80).
</div>
```